# Back button stopped to work in only one Activity

Tags: android, android-navigation

Back button stopped to work in only one Activity. I have three activities which have the same parent. But one of them stopped to back (CurrentMovieActivity). I can't figure out why. Manifest seems to be correct.

What's a possible reason for it?

My Manifest:

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_movie_white_24dp"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_movie_white_24dp"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<activity android:name=".activity.MovieActivity">
  <meta-data
    android:name="android.app.searchable"
    android:resource="@xml/searchable" />

  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
  android:label="@string/settings_title"
  android:name=".activity.SettingsActivity"
  android:parentActivityName=".activity.MovieActivity" />
<activity
  android:label="@string/current_title"
  android:name=".activity.CurrentMovieActivity"
  android:parentActivityName=".activity.MovieActivity" />
<activity
  android:label="@string/favourites"
  android:name=".activity.FavouritesActivity"
  android:parentActivityName=".activity.MovieActivity" />

<provider
  android:authorities="com.globallogic.v_holodynskyi.imdbclient"
  android:exported="false"
  android:name=".database.MovieProvider" />
```

I also tried to change launch mode and to override `onBackPress`. It looks like this, but I can't see any logs:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  Log.i(LOG_TAG, "back pressed1");
  super.onBackPressed();
  Log.i(LOG_TAG, "back pressed2");
}
```

My "broken" activity:

```
public class CurrentMovieActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private static final String LOG_TAG = CurrentMovieActivity.class.getSimpleName();

  private ImageView mPoster;
  private TextView mMovieTitle;
  private TextView mMovieDescription;
  private FloatingActionButton mFloatingButton;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_current_movie);

    initializeVariables();
  }

  @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "back pressed1");
    super.onBackPressed();
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "back pressed2");
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.current_menu, menu);
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.action_favourite:
        Intent openFavourite = new Intent(this, FavouritesActivity.class);
        startActivity(openFavourite);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
    return true;
  }

  private void initializeVariables() {
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    final String title = intent.getExtras().getString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT + TITLE);
    final String overview = intent.getExtras().getString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT + DESCRIPTION);
    final String posterLocation = intent.getExtras().getString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT + LOCATION);

    mPoster = findViewById(R.id.iv_movie_poster_current);
    downloadImage(posterLocation, mPoster);

    mMovieTitle = findViewById(R.id.tv_movie_title);
    mMovieTitle.setText(title);

    mMovieDescription = findViewById(R.id.tv_movie_description_current);
    mMovieDescription.setText(overview);

    mFloatingButton = findViewById(R.id.fb_add_to_favourites);
    mFloatingButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        saveMovie(CurrentMovieActivity.this, title, overview, posterLocation, CONTENT_URI);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Show your Activity's java file. Also if you're only going back with back button and doing nothing else, simply remove onBackPressed() method. No need to override it.

Comment: @Danger
Firstly it was without onBackPressed, I just try different ways. The problem is that other activities are the same and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because of using [android:parentActivityName](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#parent). When you using the attribute, it makes your code checking for `android.R.id.home` in `onOptionsItemSelected` method.

You need to check for `android.R.id.home` and **don't use a default** case in the switch like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
    ...
    case android.R.id.home:
      finish(); // call finish and don't use default case.
      break;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Here is related documentation: [Providing Up Navigation](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html)

Answer (score 1):

check for override **onBackPress()** code as either you have deleted the code inside it. add finish() inside the **onBackPress()**,.